# Multiple Config Files in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, app-config

In a Visual Studio 2013, C# Windows Forms there is a auto-generated settings file app.config and auto-generated Settings class accessed via Properties.Settings.Default.  What I would like to do is have multiple instances of this class reading from various files for the settings.  I won't know until run time which of the files to use for my settings.  What I want to be able to write is something like:

```
static Settings HardwareVersion1 = new Settings ("HardwareVersion1.config");
static Settings HardwareVersion2 = new Settings ("HardwareVersion2.config");
...
if (HWVersion == 1) 
localSetting = Properties.Settings.HardwareVersion1.SomeSetting;
if (HWVersion == 2)
localSetting = Properties.Settings.HardwareVersion2.SomeSetting;
```

Is there a way to accomplish this, or something close to it?  Oh and while I'm wishing, I'd like for the version specific config files to only contain overrides for the values they change from the default app.config file.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/articles/64871.aspx

Comment: What's the problem with using multiple `.settings` files?

Comment: I don't see how that solves things.  A new settings file will be of a diferent type than the original settings file.  It will be of type Settings1 for instance.  that doesn't help unless I'm missing something.